# What is $\mathbb{E}\!\left(X^2 \mid X + 2Y \right)$ if $X,Y \sim \mathcal{U}\left(\left[-1,1\right]\right)$ independently?

Tags: probability, probability-distributions, conditional-expectation, uniform-distribution

$X$ and $Y$ are independent random variables of the uniform distribution on $\left[-1,1\right]$, $X,Y \sim \mathcal{U}\!\left(\left[-1,1\right]\right)$.

What is $\mathbb{E}\!\left(X^2 \mid  X + 2Y \right)$?

My attempt:

We need the joint pdf of $X$ and $X+2Y$ (as suggested). So we do a change of variables, let $W = X,~Z = X + 2Y$. This is a linear transformation, so the jacobian will be a constant. We need to find the image of the square $-1 \leq x, y \leq 1$ under this transformation. Since it is a linear transformation, the four edges of boundaries will be mapped to line segments. So we can find them by computing where the four corners of the square are mapped:

$$\begin{align}
\left(x,y\right)&|\left(w,z\right)\\
(-1,-1) &| (-1, -3)\\
(-1,+1) &| (-1,+1)\\
(+1,+1) &| (+1,+3)\\
(+1,-1) &| (+1,-1)
\end{align}$$

The image of the square is the parallelogram with vertices as above and in the picture below:

[image]

The joint density of $W$ and $Z$ will be uniform on this region, let A denote the interior of the parallelogram. Since it has area of 8, we can conclude

$f_{W,Z}\left(w,z\right) = \frac{1}{8}\unicode{x1D7D9}\left(\left(w,z\right) \in A\right) = \begin{cases}
\frac{1}{8},  & \text{if $-1\leq w \leq 1,~-2+w\leq z\leq2+w$} \\
0, & \text{otherwise}
\end{cases}.$

The computations for $\mathbb{E}\left(X|X+2Y\right)$ and $\mathbb{E}\left(X^2|X+2Y\right)$ are below.

---

(for $\mathbb{E}\left(X|X+2Y\right)$, $Z = X + 2Y$)

Now we can figure out what $f_{X|Z}\left(x|z\right)$ is. We must consider three cases:

1. $-3 \leq z \leq -1$, given $Z = z$, $X$ is uniformly distributed between $-1$ and $z+2$. So $\mathbb{E}\!\left(X|Z=z\right) = \frac{-1+2+z}{2} = \frac{z}{2} + \frac{1}{2}$
2. $-1 \leq z \leq 1$, given $Z = z$, $X$ is uniformly distributed between $-1$ and $1$. So $\mathbb{E}\!\left(X|Z=z\right) = \frac{-1+1}{2} = 0$
3. $1 \leq z \leq 3$, given $Z = z$, $X$ is uniformly distributed between $1$ and $z-2$. So $\mathbb{E}\!\left(X|Z=z\right) = \frac{1-2+z}{2} = \frac{z}{2} - \frac{1}{2}$

Cases $1,2,3$ (with $0$ otherwise) gives us $\mathbb{E}\!\left(X|Z=z\right)$.

---

(for $\mathbb{E}\left(X^2|X+2Y\right)$, $Z = X + 2Y$)

We must consider three cases:

1. $-3 < z \leq -1$, given $Z = z$, $X$ is uniformly distributed between $-1$ and $z+2$ (so probability density function $f_{X|Z}(x|z) = \frac{1}{(z+2) - (-1)} = \frac{1}{z+3}$). So $\mathbb{E}\!\left(X^2|Z=z\right) = \int_{-1}^{z+2}x^2 \cdot \frac{1}{z+3}dx = \frac{1}{3} \cdot \frac{(z+2)^3+1}{z+3}$
2. $-1 \leq z \leq 1$, given $Z = z$, $X$ is uniformly distributed between $-1$ and $1$ (probability density function $f_{X|Z}(x|z) = \frac{1}{2}$).
   So $\mathbb{E}\!\left(X^2|Z=z\right) = \int_{-1}^{1}x^2 \cdot \frac{1}{2}dx = \frac{1}{3}$
3. $1 \leq z < 3$, given $Z = z$, $X$ is uniformly distributed between $1$ and $z-2$. So $\mathbb{E}\!\left(X^2|Z=z\right) = \int_1^{z-2}x^2\frac{1}{z-3}dx = \frac{1}{3}\cdot\frac{1}{z-3}\cdot\left((z-2)^3-1\right)$

Cases $1,2,3$ (with $0$ otherwise) gives us $\mathbb{E}\!\left(X^2|Z=z\right)$.

Comment: Please share your thoughts.

Comment: Begin with by determining the joint distribution of $X$ and $X＋2Y$.

Comment: @Zhanxiong I tried to determine the joint distribution and calculated $\mathbb{E}\!\left(X|X+2Y\right)$, but I am not sure how to proceed with $\mathbb{E}\!\left(X^2|X+2Y\right)$.

Comment: @StubbornAtom My attempt is in the edition of the post.

Comment: @ljaniec In general, if you have determined $f_{X|Z}(x|z)$, then theoretically you can determine $E[g(X) | Z]$ for any Borel function $g$ by calculating $\int g(x)f_{X|Z}(x|z) dx$. Just take $g(x) = x^2$ to proceed.

Comment: @ljaniec For example, in your case 1, $E(X^2 | Z = z) = \int_{-1}^{2 + z} x^2 \frac{1}{3 + z} dx = \cdots $.

Comment: @Zhanxiong Could you explain me how did you get $\frac{1}{3+z}$ as $f_{X|Z}(x|z)$? It is result of the $f_{X|Z}(x,z) = \frac{f_{X,Z(x,z)}}{f_{Z}(z)}$, when $f_Z(z)\neq 0$, $0$ otherwise, right? When I tried to get $f_Z(z)$ by integrating $f_{X,Z}$ over $w$ on $(-1,1)$, I got $\frac{1}{4}$ and other end result. I am not sure if I used the correct way there too.

Comment: @ljaniec I quoted your own statement: "$-3 \leq z \leq -1$, given $Z = z$, $X$ is uniformly distributed between $-1$ and $2+z$", which means the conditional distribution of $X$ given $Z = z$ is $U(-1, 2 + z)$.

Comment: @Zhanxiong Thank you for clarification, I really overthought it there. So it is CDF of uniform distribution on $(-1, 2 + z)$. I will try edit the whole post with the end result for check soon. If you write these hints as an answer, I will accept it.

Comment: @ljaniec I am glad if it helps. I think you made a very nice plot and presented your work neatly! Great job! Keep up the good work!

Comment: @Zhanxiong Does the solution in the new edit is correct? Thanks.

Comment: @ljaniec Correct. For perfection, check the boundary case once more: say, if $z = -3$, can you still write $\frac{1}{z + 3}$?

Comment: @Zhanxiong You're right, I assume the it is zero for $z = -3$ (set of measure zero) and so on. Is it correct?

Answer (score 0):

Observe that

- $X|(X+2Y = k) \sim \text{Unif}(-1,1)$ for $k\in[-1,1]$;
- $X|(X+2Y = k) \sim \text{Unif}(-1,2+k)$ for $k\in (-3,-1)$ and
- $X|(X+2Y = k) \sim \text{Unif}(k-2,1)$ for $k\in (1,3)$

Therefore,

- $\mathbb{E}(X^2|X+2Y = k) =\displaystyle\int_{-1}^1 \frac{1}{2}(x^2)dx = \frac{1}{3}$ for $k\in[-1,1]$;
- $\mathbb{E}(X^2|X+2Y = k) =\displaystyle\int_{-1}^{2+k} \frac{x^2}{3+k}dx = \frac{(2+k)^3+1}{3(3+k)}$ for $k\in (-3,-1)$ and
- $\mathbb{E}(X^2|X+2Y = k) =\displaystyle\int_{k-2}^{1} \frac{x^2}{3-k}dx = \frac{1-(k-2)^3}{3(3-k)}$ for $k\in[1,3]$

Answer (score -1):

Define $h:\mathbb{R} \to \mathbb{R}$ such that $h(x)=\frac 1 3 \chi_{[-3,3]}$.

The claim is that $\mathbb{E}\left(X^2 | X + 2Y \right)=h(X+2Y)$.

---

Suppose $B \in \mathscr{B}([-3,3])$.

Let us prove $\int \chi_{B}(x+2y)x^2dx dy=\int \chi_{B}(x+2y)h(x+2y)dxdy$.

If $g(x,y)=(x+2y,x)$ then $|\det g (x,y)|=2$ and thus we have to prove
$$\int_{[-3,3]\times [0,1]} \chi_{B}(z)x^2dz dx=\int_{[-3,3]\times [0,1]} \chi_{B}(z)h(z)dzdx$$

thanks to the change of variable.

Now $\int_{[-3,3]\times [0,1]} \chi_{B}(z)x^2dz dx=\mu(B)\frac 1 3$ and $\int_{[-3,3]\times [0,1]} \chi_{B}(z)h(z)dzdx=\int_{[-3,3]\times [0,1]} \chi_{B}(z)\frac 1 3 dzdx=\mu(B)\frac 1 3$ which conclude the proof.

Comment: I am not sure if I understood your solution. Could you elaborate for me the part which starts at $g(x,y)=...$?